# How can I read each key values

Tags: c#, json

I am reading the cost value below

original data look like :-

```html
 {
   "Key":"Cost",
   "Value":[
      {
         "Key":"a",
         "Value":5.25
      },
      {
         "Key":"b",
         "Value":0
      },
      {
         "Key":"c",
         "Value":5.25
      },
      {
         "Key":"d",
         "Value":0
      }
   ]
}
```

My expected result is I need to read a,b,c,d not data["Cost"].

How can I read each separately

Comment: That is not valid JSON - the outer `{}` indicates an object with properties, but you have an array directly inside the brackets. There's no way to process this with a standard JSON parser.

Comment: i edited and added the original json value can you please help

Comment: First define a class that matches the json and then deserialize to that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(myJsonResponse);
//myDeserializedClass.Value will contain all key and value
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

classes generated through https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to convert a json to a dictionary

```
var costs= JObject.Parse(json)["Value"]
                  .ToDictionary(j => (string) j["Key"], j=> (decimal) j["Value"] );

decimal c  = costs["c"]; //5.25
```

or using dynamic

```
var dict = JObject.Parse(json)["Value"]
                    .ToDictionary(j => (string)j["Key"], j => (object)j["Value"]);

dynamic costs = dict.Aggregate(new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>,
                                (a, p) => { a.Add(p); return a; });
decimal c = costs.c;
```